# Not able to convert this sql query into Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

```
select count(listings.price) 
from generate_series(0,400) s(d) 
left outer join listings listings 
on (s.d <= (listings.price/25000) and (listings.price/25000) <= (1+ s.d))  
group by s.d 
order by s.d;
```

Comment: what is `generate_series(0,400) s(d)`? I haven't seen such thing

Comment: And I don't think you can convert such a query with is not running on proper table to rails

Comment: generate_series(0,400) will generate a table with number 0 to 400, actually this is working for me as raw query

Comment: ohh.. Interesting but then why are you using query for just numbers? Can;t you use another approach?

Comment: can you please post the expected output? maybe we can think of another approach

Comment: basically it's a "count price in interval", generate_series is used for interval then on condition filter out the results that belongs to particular interval and there is 25000 is used for normalisation the price

Comment: @Sanju Meena what database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try [eql](https://github.com/zoer/eql) gem. In this gem you can use erb template into sql query

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figure out the another way to implement the same query and here is my updated query.
`Listing.select("COUNT(price_interval) as count, price_interval").from(listings.select("FLOOR(price/25000) as price_interval").references(:listings)).group(:price_interval)`